# spring test mock static method globally

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito

in spring test, I know I can mock static method(usually static util methods: generate id, get value from Redis) using Mockito like:

```
try (MockedStatic) {
}
```

but having to do this in every test method is ugly and cumbersome, is there any way to do it all(i am ok to have a single mocked behavior)

I am thinking maybe a junit5 extension, or Mockito extension, this seems like a common problem, I wonder if anyone tries something with any success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```java
public class StaticClassTest {

    MockedStatic<YourStatic> mockedStatic;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(YourStatic.class);

        // if you want the same behavior all along.
        mockedStatic.when(() -> YourStatic.doSomething(anyString())).thenReturn("TEST");
    }
    
    @Test
    public void test_static() {
        // write your test here
    }


    @After
    public void teardown() {
        mockedStatic.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: why do i have to close it in @aftereach?

Comment: It's a standard practice of `MockedStatic`, just like closing DB Connection after a SQL query.
So you can use either `try-with-resources` in every test case (like your example), or my answer.
See more: https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods#mocking-a-no-argument-static-method

Comment: if I want the same behavior all along, so I don't have to close it?

Comment: I recommend doing setup/teardown every time, otherwise it might occur concurrency issue in some complexity situation. It's good to setup/teardown every time to make every test cases more independent and clean. By the way, I have improved my answer to make the mock do same behavior all along.